# OpenGL color/alpha output slightly dimmed

Tags: linux, opengl, colors, alpha

I'm seeing slightly dimmed color/alpha output from OpenGL in Linux.  Instead of seeing a red component value of 1.0 I'm seeing ~.96988.  For example, I have a fully red rectangle (red component = 1.0, alpha = 1.0, green and blue are zero).  This dimming happens whether I enable my vertex/fragment shaders or not.

Lighting is disabled so no ambient or other light should be included in the color calculation.

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(1.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(0.0, 1.0);
glEnd();
```

I take a screen-shot of the resulting window and then load the image into a paint program and examine any particular pixel.  I see a red component integer value of 247 instead of 255 as I would expect.  When I run this with the vertex shader enabled I see the gl_Color.r component is already < 1.0 and the gl_Color.a component is as well.

All OpenGL states are at the default values. What am I missing?

Edit due to question:
I determined that the value of the red component was ~.96988 by a crude and iterative process of inspecting it in the vertex shader and altering the blue component to signal when the red component was above a threshold value. I kept reducing the constant threashold value until I no longer saw purple.  This did the trick:

```
if(gl_Color.r > 0.96988)
{
    gl_Color.b = 1.0;  \\ show purple instead of the slightly dimmed red.
}
```

Edit:

```
//VERTEX SHADER
varying vec2 texture_coordinate;
void main()
{
   gl_Position = ftransform();
   texture_coordinate = vec2(gl_MultiTexCoord0);
   gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
}


//FRAGMENT SHADER
varying vec2 texture_coordinate;
uniform sampler2D Texture0;
void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture0, texture_coordinate) * gl_Color;
}
```

Texture0 in this instance is a fully saturated RED rectangle Red = 1.0, Alpha = 1.0.  Without the texture, using vertex color, I get the same results; a slightly dimminished Red and Alpha component.

One more thing, the Red and Aplha channels are "dimmed" by the same amount. So something is causing a dimming of the entire color component.  And as I stated in the main question this occurs whether I use shaders or the fixed punction pipeline.

Just for fun I performed a similar test in Windows using DirectX and this resulted in a rectangle with a Red component of 254; still slightly dimmed but just barely.

Comment: May I know please where you see the value ~.96988.

I guess it is quite normal working with floating point values.

Comment: Do you have a compositor running?  If so, make sure it isn't playing games with your window output via a plugin or somesuch.

Comment: Does the driver have a gamma set?

Comment: @MartinBeckett: Gamma correction does not alter a 1 or 0; 0^g = 0, 1^g = 1. I suspect, that some color management may bite the OP, or maybe there's still some texture bound.

Comment: @datenwolf - done properly it doesn't. But implemented in a Windows driver who knows!

Comment: I appologize for not responding sooner. I received no notification from StackOverflow that comments were posted.

Comment: @genpfault - I don't know what a compositor is.

Comment: @Martin Beckett - "Does the driver have a gamma set?" Not that I can determine.  Everything appears to be stock.

Comment: Can you show us the vertex and fragment shaders you use?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas - Question editted to include shaders; but as I state in the original question this problem occurs with or without shaders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because I resolved the issue and I was the cause.  It turns out that I was incorrectly calculating the color channels, including alpha, for the vertices in my models when converting from binary to floating point.  A silly error that introduced this slight dimming.

For instance:

```
currentColor = m_pVertices[i].clr; // color format ARGB
float a = (1.0 / 256) * (m_pVertices[i].clr >> 24);
float r = (1.0 / 256) * ((m_pVertices[i].clr >> 16) % 256);
float g = (1.0 / 256) * ((m_pVertices[i].clr >> 8) % 256);
float b = (1.0 / 256) * (m_pVertices[i].clr % 256);
glColor4f(r, g, b, a);
```

I should be dividing by 255. Doh!

It seems the only dimming is in my brain and not in openGL.